# AWS glue conditional select sql (pyspark)

Tags: aws-glue

I am an aws glue newbie , need inputs on how to do following.

1. i need to select dynamic fram from redshift using **SQL1**
2. **SQL1** = SELECT table1.new_cust_id , table2.src_id , table2.email_address , table2.create_ts FROM table1 , table2 **WHERE** table1.old_cust_id = table2.cust_id

i am not sure how to do it.
I am aware of glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(...) but my understanding is that create_dynamic_frame_from_options api creates whole DF ... never seen any exampe of SQL with a where clause to create A dynamic frame

As an alternate , i know there is an API

- create a spark DF1 ( all rows of table1 )
- create a spark DF2 ( all rows of table2 )
- use a join API
  but the issue is each table has 55 million records , so i want to use SQL approach